# Keyboard language self switches

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, input-language

I'm on 13.10. I have an italian layout and sometimes while typing my layout self switches to soemthing different, and my modifiers (alt gr) do not work as expected anymore. I have to go to the inicator and choose "it" again. Then the keyboard works again.

Anybody else got this issue?
Any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue unless it is not while typing but every time I login/boot. It is English US and not my default language...

I found out, that when you accidentally press "Shift + Super + Space" it does change the keyboard input language. You can change the shortcut in your Keyboard-Settings.

Comment: Are you using Xfce?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use program called `setxkbmap`. Try to add this after run :

```
setxkbmap us
```

(Add this command to startup applications)

Where "us" is your prefered language... This should change your keyboard layout after you login.

You can also set keyboard switching for example with alt + shift:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle cz,us
```

Where "cz,us" specify languages that will be switching.

Hope [this](http://tuxilero.blogspot.cz/2013/09/linux-how-to-keyboard-layouts-in-linux.html) help :)

Comment: A native solution would be better, tbh.

Comment: It works - so I consider the self switching a bug...

Comment: It worked once - now it doesn't anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **keyboard layout** :

[image]

Just choose the same layout for all windows .

Comment: I think that he checked the obvious settings. The sudden change - or for me the diffent language on start-up - is the problem.