# Keyboard language is different every log in

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I set my keyboard to german - and it is the only language selected. Nevertheless, every time I log in, the keyboard language is somehow English.

(This bug is similar to this one: [Keyboard language self switches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367745/keyboard-language-self-switches) - but it is not the same.)

I also set `setxkbmap de` as a startup application, but it only worked once. Since then it is English every time I boot my laptop.

I am running 13.10 64 bit - and I checked all the obvious solutions (keyboard layout etc.). Is there any solution or is it a bug?

Comment: Is German the only language in the list in `System Settings -> Text Entry`?

Comment: Yes. That is the strange thing...

Comment: Then it's most likely a bug. I think that 14.04 works more reliably in this respect, so you may want to do an early upgrade...

Comment: Cheers mate. SUddenly, it changed. I did not do a thing... Strange.