# Accents stop working all of a sudden in Libreoffice

Tags: keyboard, kde, libreoffice, keyboard-layout, 14.04

I can write characters such as á, é, ó, ã, ê, etc just fine in Kubuntu 14.04.

Even in LibreOffice.

However, if I switch windows from LibreOffice to, say, Chrome or even Dolphin, and then I switch back to LibreOffice, these characters will not register anymore and instead plain a, e, o , a, e will be written, with no accents.

This is very annoying and I've been fiddling with KDE System Settings for the past couple of hours unsuccessfully. I'd really like some help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You will probably find the answer/solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367745/keyboard-language-self-switches; the cause is (I think) the same. The answer of nux is probably what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue. I also notice that this problem is KDE and IBUS related. Solution above didn't work at all. It seems that other similar issues may be related to this package combination (KDE, ibus, libreoffice-kde). I solved it in my system by removing *libreoffice-kde* and keeping *libreoffice-gnome*.

Links that may help:

1. Same problem, in Fedora 16, and the solution in comment n. 5 : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825067
2. Same, in openSUSE: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/473607-Ibus-don-t-work-in-Libreoffice-%28Opensuse-12-1%29

Answer (score 1):

What helped to me was to remove libreoffice-kde package.

I also uninstalled all english languages in KDE and Unity and left only one (my, czech).

Now it seems OK so I think removal of libreoffice-kde package was way to help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Vlijm gave me this very helpful link:

[Keyboard language self switches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367745/keyboard-language-self-switches)

My solution was the one given by Adobe. I killed ibus and everything worked; having found the culprit, I opened it again and went through its preferences to fix the issue.

Comment: It all worked until I started having problems with [Chrome](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470300/cant-type-accents-in-uppercase-letters-in-chrome). So now with ibus, Libreoffice is broken; without ibus, Chrome is broken. I'm going to try Luan Carvalho's option above and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had te same problem and i did uninstall libreoffice-kde and it work

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libreoffice-kde
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing `/etc/default/locale` and rebooting after does solve it also; this situation happens when there are several languages set at "locale". one that works is setting `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` and all other `pt_PT.UTF-8` with a LibreOffice in English, and Portuguese for the rest. Or just changing LANGUAGE.

Answer (score 0):

I was having thins problem on KDE Neon (a ubuntu derivitave), using e_CA.UTF-8 and fr_CA.UTF-8 locales, and the Canadian multilingual keyboard. Launching Libreoffice from the command line gave me these warnings:

```
I18N: Operating system doesn't support locale ""
I18N: Operating system doesn't support locale "en_US"
```

I don't have any idea what the en_US locale has to do with accented characters, but building the en_US ISO-8859-1 locale fixed the problem for me (I had only built en_US.UTF-8). To do this, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and select en_US ISO-8859-1 as well as any other locales you are using.