# Can't type accents in uppercase letters in Chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, kde, libreoffice

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 with the latest Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114) and while inside any Chrome window I can't really type accented uppercase letters. So, for instance, these

é á ã ó ò

are perfectly fine. But these

Á É À Ó Ã

I had to type in a LibreOffice window and paste here.

I really don't know what is going on and would really appreciate any help =/

Comment: [This](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363037) is close to the problem that you have.